# Saying Harei At Mkudeshet Li

Tags: marriage

If someone gives a girl a ring in front of a group of Jews and says "Harei at mkudeshet li" while they are dating does she now need a get to marry someone else after they break up?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. And that is why people have to be careful with saying that.

Comment: I remember this happening even in a joking scenario and they needed to go through the whole rigmarole!

Comment: Even if they're not dating

Comment: See Shu"t Atzei Besamim for in depth discussion, you can also see Rav Jachter on this inyan in Gray matter

Comment: See link to a similar situation https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/israel-news/1806993/ashdod-beis-din-rules-on-marriage-of-two-children-in-paris.html

Comment: @sam, what section/page talks about it in gray matters?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Gray_Matter_III%2C_Family_Matters%2C_Frivolous_Wedding_Ceremonies.1?lang=bi

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, @BobShmo! How's your cousin Yosef?